# What are some materias/substances that can be applied to a ball such that the ball will stck to a wall,if thrown

Tags: adhesion

I am trying to make a prototype for the "valkyrie camera" seen in the video game Rainbow 6 Siege
This is how it works
https://gfycat.com/impressivegrippingauklet
the black ball seen is the camera,as you can see the camera is thrown and it sticks to a surface.
are there any materials that are capable of such action?

Comment: The trajectory of the ball seems non-physical, I wonder how they simulated that. In any case, the ball itself seems to be a hollow plastic sphere containing the camera, and the system within is activated by pressing somewhere on its surface. This is a non-stick ball when in your hand and yet it sticks upon contact with other surfaces, remaining attached under the weight of camera plus sphere. It might be coated with a thin layer of transparent adhesive (otherwise the camera would not clearly resolve whatever is outside the ball).

Comment: Seems impossible. I would suggest making the ball morph into a "sticky" form after casting, either using a timer or a sensor. An impact sensor which causes some attachment mechanism to extend seems a reasonable solution. I would not use an adhesive.

Comment: Memories of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wacky_WallWalker come to mind. Our cats would go nuts watching them slowly ‘walk’ down walls until they could pounce...

Comment: What if we designate an area as "hold-able" while the rest of the surface is covered by the "sticky material X" .X will have a cover which can be removed before deployment.I am mostly curious whether an X exists that is sticky enough to as has been noted before to sustain                                                                                                                                    Weight of ball + equipment.                                                                                                         impulse generated on impact.

Comment: A magnet, perhaps?

Comment: I am afraid a magnet cannot be used as the ball must stick to nonmagnetic surfaces.